# Is binary tree a binary search tree if tree is spread over multiple machines

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I know the algorithm to check if a given binary tree is a binary search tree. But considering that the tree doesn't reside entirely on the same machine but is spread across multiple machines, what should I do to handle such scenarios ?  On single machines, I use the range check method at every node of the tree to check if its a BST or not.  Is there any resource where I can read to handle this kind of question where the data is not necessarily on the same system ?

Comment: I think it would be better if you also told where such problem arises.

Comment: Why do you think "the range check method" would be a problem when the BST is split across multiple machines? I haven't heard of "the range check method", but it sounds like the intuitive approach of passing the left and right boundaries to any given subtree recursively (solving the problem by visiting each node once), which can be parallelised just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BST has a property. it's each children will also be a BST. validate all the machine's binary tree and once you have the each machine BT is BST then get the root node of each machine's BT and then again validate the tree if it is BST from the root node.

Comment: Good insight !! I thinks this is what I was looking for.

Comment: another approach could be ..BST inorder gives you sorted list. just do the inorder traversal at each node's BT and check if it is sorted, If not then return false else do as get root node from each machine and validate BST.